# Постановка запятой перед союзом "и" при однородных местоимениях

Tags: союзы

В предложении "Я пришёл и я победил" нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

Answer (score 3):

Местоимение — это часть речи, а термин "однородные" может относиться только к предложениям или их членам.
Предложение *Я пришёл, и я победил* является сложносочиненным, запятая перед союзом "и" **ставится**.
У [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) есть по этому поводу примечание:

> Перед союзом ***и*** запятая ставится также в тех случаях, когда он
> присоединяет предложение, в котором подлежащее выражено личным
> местоимением, относящимся к подлежащему первой части сложносочиненного
> предложения или повторяющим его: ...*Ты всегда был строг ко мне, и ты
> был справедлив* (Т.).

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без запятой обойтись: ***Я пришёл — и я победил!***

А при постановке запятой и без восклицательного знака получается "вялое бормотание" без особого смысла.

§ 32. Тире в сложносочиненном предложении

1. Если во второй части сложносочиненного предложения содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое **противопоставление,** то между частями перед сочинительным союзом вместо запятой ставится тире.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135